# Подключение к базе Oracle на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, база-данных, oracle

Я прописываю:

```
import cx_Oracle
conn = cx_Oracle.connect('login/password@server/alias')
```

Выдаёт такую ошибку:

> cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: 64-bit Oracle Client library cannot be loaded: "C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin\oci.dll is not the correct architecture".

Версия python и oracle 64-битные. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: в `PATH` ссылка одна и на правильный клиент?

Comment: правильно ли я понимаю, что у меня там должен быть прописан путь к интерпретатору, В моём случае ..\AppData\Local\Continuum\Python36 ?

Comment: C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin;
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;
C:\Windows\system32;
C:\Windows;
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Users\emedyanik\AppData\Local\Continuum\Python36

Comment: где то у вас архитектура (битность) не совпадает - проверьте аохитектуру Python, Oracle Client, cx_Oracle

Comment: да, вы правы. я проверяла сервер на архитектуру, он 64, а клиент оказался 32